How can I manage long package lists in sh without arrays?
I'm using FreeBSD, and the shell is "sh". I want to make a simple script to install a list of packages. Normally, I'd use an array to store the package names, but since "sh" doesn't support arrays, I think the best way is to use a space-separated string, like this:
packages="nameofpackage1 nameofpackage2 nameofpackage3"

The problem with this approach is that when I have a lot of packages and want to keep them in alphabetical order, adding a new package later means I have to rearrange the entire list keeping the 80 characters per line in mind as well. It makes the structure harder to manage over time.
I think it would be nicer to list the packages in a "list" layout. That makes inserting new packages easier, just adding a new line. However, from what I understand, that means I'd need to use the \ character to continue the line. If there are many packages, there will be a lot of \ characters. Does that cause any issues for sh?
packages="package_a \
          package_b \
          package_c \
          package_d \
          and so on"

Is there a better way to do this? If you have any suggestions, I'd really appreciate it.

There is one list in sh: the list of positional parameters. Are you using that for anything in the script?

No. I'm not using that list. But is there anything wrong in having those \ symbols?

Well, the backslashes aren't needed in your example, but with or without them you still only have a string, not a list.

The backslashes in your example aren't needed because you would need to let the shell split the string anyway, and it would, by default, split on spaces, tabs, and newlines. So whether or not the newlines in the string are escaped or not really doesn't matter.
The issue with demoting the list of packages to a single string is that to use the individual package names in loops or do whatever you want to do with them, you must (let the shell) split the string by leaving it unquoted.  Now, that may be alright in the simple cases where package names contain no whitespace or globbing characters, but as soon as you need to deal with things like curl 8.* or similar substrings, the splitting and globbing action of the shell will be challenging to get right in all cases.
Instead, use the list of positional parameters:
set -- \
    package_a \
    package_b \
    package_c \
    package_d \
    'My weird *** package' \
    'Bumblebees 2.0'

You may then refer to the list using "$@".
You may loop over the packages using
for package do
    # do something with "$package"
done

or, if you like typing,
for package in "$@"; do
    # do something with "$package"
done


Thank you. It looks great. Can the list of positional arguments be used only once in a script?

@ZoltanKing No, but if you were using the list for something else, then you obviously wouldn’t be able to store the list of packages in it.

Do you mean, each time it is used, the list gets cleared? That is fine. Because once a series of packages are installed they are no longer need to be installed again, but maybe I want the list for another list of packages in the same script.

@ZoltanKing No, the list only gets reset when you set it. I mean, if you use it for one thing (like parsing the command line arguments), you can't at the same time use it for something else (not until you're done using it for whatever other thing you're using it for in the script).
